# Hiding the android keyboard does not work

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, android-softkeyboard

I'm building an application of `Html5` + `PhoneGap` for `Android`.

I want that when a function call the Android keyboard be **hidden**.

I tried to do it in the following way:

```
function HideKeyboard() {
        alert('HideKeyboard');
        plugins.SoftKeyBoard.hide(function () {
              alert('s');
            }, function () {
             alert('f');
           });
        }
```

It did not work! There is another way?

the alert 'HideKeyboard' appears, but other messages do not appear

Here my plugin:

```
 <plugin name="SoftKeyBoard" value="com.phonegap.plugins.SoftKeyboard.SoftKeyBoard" />
```

*Thank you ..*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you:

1. Create `/src/org/apache/cordova/plugins` with `SoftKeyBoard.java` in it
2. Add the plugin definition to `/res/xml/plugins.xml`:

   ```
   <plugin name="SoftKeyBoard"
          value="org.apache.cordova.plugins.SoftKeyBoard" />
   ```
3. Add `softkeyboard.js` to `/assets/www/js`
4. Add to the `head` in `index.html` a reference to `softkeyboard.js`:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript"
        charset="utf-8"
            src="js/softkeyboard.js"></script>
   ```
5. Finally call the following on the device:

   ```
   window.cordova.plugins.SoftKeyBoard.hide(function () {
     // WooHoo!
   },function () {
     // BooHoo!
   });
   ```

So far I can only see that you've done step 2 & 5.

**Updated** it was a namespace issue it seems, and I've also updated to reflect that. Glad it worked.

Comment: I do steps 2 and 5.. where i get softkeyboard.js? and  SoftKeyBoard.java?

Comment: @HodayaShalom yeah I was just fixing that 5 to read 2 & 5 while you commented. Also I changed `.show` to `.hide`.

Comment: Can u explain step 1? and tell me where can I get softkeyboard.js and SoftKeyBoard.java? –

Comment: @HodayaShalom That path might be an old version of phonegap from my book; perhaps you're using the new version and need to put the java file in `src/org/apache/cordova/plugins/SoftKeyBoard.java` ? If so I'll update my answer

Comment: I assume you get the files from github https://github.com/originalgremlin/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/SoftKeyboard

Comment: It works! Thanks, I needed to change to :window.cordova.plugins.SoftKeyBoard.hide

Comment: @HodayaShalom good to know, will update the paths to the new namespace.